# Ethernet port on Apple TV

Tags: tvos, ethernet

What ways is the Ethernet port accessible to apps in tvOS?

I can't find any documentation or mention of being able to use/access anything directly coming into the ethernet port in an app on tvOS.

EDIT: Additional INFO:

An Apple guy on their forums talking about Network access options across all OS's of Apple in their upcoming updates: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6767

In this thread he's chatting with some others about something similar, specific to Mac, but this now seems to be relevant to all upcoming Apple OS's: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6205

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why won't normal networking APIs work?

Comment: @DanielStorm we have an external controller that's not suitable nor eligible for MFi, but would like to get the lowest latency input from it into our app. With Bluetooth LE, 20ms seems to be the lowest guaranteed latency. CoreMIDI, possibly able to get as low as 6ms over Bluetooth, is not available on tvOS. WIFI is a bit of a mess, but there's that LAN port on the back, and I thought... wait a minute... maybe we can use that... but I can't find anything on sends from an external controller, through to that port, and listening via an App on tvOS.

Comment: @LukeTaylor I have no idea. In what ways are they accessible to Apps on tvOS for custom data at the lowest possible latency? Do I need to poll the port, or can I get the app to register and/or "listen"?

Answer (score 0):

Three main things you will need to do: connectivity, discovery, and communication.

The ethernet port is expecting to be connected to a network. In your case, the Apple TV and your external controllers would each need to be clients connected to that network, likely through a hub or router. If the network does not have a DHCP server, you will need to manually configure the network connection for each device.

Discovery would be the next challenge. Each device will have a unique IP address on the network and you will need to come up with a method for the Apple TV to find the controllers IP address on the network. Perhaps this can be hard-coded if you are controlling the network, or if the controller is serving as the router.

Lastly, you will need to decide on a protocol that the Apple TV and controllers use to communicate. You could use a low level protocol such as TCP or UDP, or a higher protocol like HTTP is the controller wants to act as a web server.

This is an overly broad answer to a very broad question, but there is a lot involved in getting things like this to work.

Another note is that on the Apple TV, either the ethernet port is active or the Wifi connection, but not both. Connecting the ethernet port will lose any Wifi connection.